# Display version, build date and environment of Blazor webassembly application

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, blazor-webassembly

I am trying to display the version, build date and environment variable on the NavMenu of a Blazor Webassembly application. Here is what i have tried but in vain

NavMenu.razor.cs

```
protected static Version AppVersion => Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Version?? throw new NullReferenceException();

protected DateTime BuildDate => new DateTime(2000, 1, 1).AddDays(AppVersion.Build).AddSeconds(AppVersion.Revision * 2);

protected string DisplayEnvironment => Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable(EnvironmentVariableTarget.Process) ?? throw new NullReferenceException()
```

When i run the app i get null reference exception possibly on DisplayEnvironment property.
I would appreciate any help.

Comment: `EnvironmentVariableTarget.Process` indicates where to look for an environment variable; you need to specify the name of the environment variable as well.https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.environment.getenvironmentvariable?view=net-7.0

Answer (score 4):

According to [this link](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/38987), environment variables aren't available to Blazor WebAssembly.

You can obtain the app's environment in a component by injecting [IWebAssemblyHostEnvironment](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.components.webassembly.hosting.iwebassemblyhostenvironment?view=aspnetcore-7.0) and reading the [Environment](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.components.webassembly.hosting.iwebassemblyhostenvironment.environment?view=aspnetcore-7.0#microsoft-aspnetcore-components-webassembly-hosting-iwebassemblyhostenvironment-environment) property.

```
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Hosting
@inject IWebAssemblyHostEnvironment HostEnvironment

<h1>Environment example</h1>

<p>Environment: @HostEnvironment.Environment</p>
```

Reference link: [ASP.NET Core Blazor environments](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/fundamentals/environments?view=aspnetcore-7.0#read-the-environment)

**Update:**

Version:

```
protected static Version AppVersion => System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Version ?? throw new NullReferenceException();
```

Build Date:

You can add the AssemblyTitle (or any other attribute you like) to your csproj file:

```
<PropertyGroup>
    <AssemblyTitle>$([System.DateTime]::Now)</AssemblyTitle>
</PropertyGroup>
```

If you want to format the date, you can do like this:

```
<AssemblyTitle>$([System.DateTime]::Now.ToString(yyyyMMdd-HHmm))</AssemblyTitle>
```

Then in your Blazor code:

```
string BuildInfo;
protected override void OnInitialized()
{
    Assembly curAssembly = typeof(Program).Assembly;
    BuildInfo = $"{curAssembly.GetCustomAttributes(false).OfType<AssemblyTitleAttribute>().FirstOrDefault().Title}";
}
```

Comment: That works! How about the build version and date info? Thanks for your time mate.

Comment: Hi @Riley Christian, I updated my answer, you can check it.