# Display app version in Blazor Webassembly

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, blazor-webassembly

I a trying to display the version on NavMenu bar of my blazor webassembly app.
Here is what i have tried:

```
@code {
 protected string AppVersion => Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetCustomAttribute<AssemblyInformationalVersionAttribute>()!.InformationalVersion;
```

}

When i run my application i get AppVersion as **1.0.0**.
Is that correct?

Thank you for the comment.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Display version, build date and environment of Blazor webassembly application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75189262/display-version-build-date-and-environment-of-blazor-webassembly-application)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is correct. This is the default assembly version.

If you want to change the version number, you can add `Version` in the .csproj file:

```
<PropertyGroup>
    <Version>2.0.0.0</Version>
</PropertyGroup>
```

When you perform a `Build` operation on the project, you can see that the `AssemblyVersionAttribute`, `AssemblyInformationalVersionAttribute` and `AssemblyFileVersionAttribute` in the `ProjectName.AssemblyInfo.cs` file(in \obj\Debug\net6.0) changes accordingly (the default is `1.0.0.0`):

```
[assembly: System.Reflection.AssemblyFileVersionAttribute("2.0.0.0")]
[assembly: System.Reflection.AssemblyInformationalVersionAttribute("2.0.0.0")]
[assembly: System.Reflection.AssemblyVersionAttribute("2.0.0.0")]
```